# Full-Text Search in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

How would you implement a "poor man's" full text search in Javascript?

I'm implementing a static webpage with no database backend, and the page loads a few thousand records of short text strings via an Ajax JSON load. I'd like the user to be able to efficiently filter these strings via keyword search, ideally with something a little smarter than simply iterating over each string and doing a Javascript `.indexOf()`.

I thought about rendering my JSON to hidden HTML, and using a jQuery DOM search plugin, but I doubt that would be faster than iterating over my JSON list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> a few thousand records

This is not that much, have a look at the [Full-Text Search in JavaScript](http://burakkanber.com/blog/machine-learning-full-text-search-in-javascript-relevance-scoring/) with a demo of full-text search in 40k rows.

> .indexOf()

JavaScript is a bit limited when it comes to text manipulation, but this will do the job.

Here is a pretty straightforward manual that is perfectly fitting to your question. [Jekyll + lunr.js = Static websites with powerful full-text search using JavaScript](http://10consulting.com/2013/03/06/jekyll-and-lunr-js-static-websites-with-powerful-full-text-search-using-javascript/)

I have experience of building static web-pages with smaller amounts of data and usually, performance is the last issue on the way.

Answer (score 1):

#### Fuzzy-search variant using *Fuse.js* instead of Jquery

As you propably also want to have a **fuzzy search** nowadays. You could use a lib like [Fuse.js (demo)](https://fusejs.io/demo.html) to very easily search an **array of (nested) objects** - this should be as complicated as the "poor mans" approach, but way more effective

E.g. if you have an array ob objects:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Old Man's War",
    "author": "John Scalzi",
    "tags": ["fiction"]
  },
  {
    "title": "The Lock Artist",
    "author": "Steve",
    "tags": ["thriller"]
  }
]
```

To search simply use `fuse.search('text')` after initialization.

```
const options = {
  includeScore: true,
  // Search in `author` and in `tags` array
  keys: ['author', 'tags']
}

const fuse = new Fuse(list, options)

const result = fuse.search('OldMans War')
```

See the [list of options](https://fusejs.io/api/options.html) to limit results.

Answer (score -2):

Another solution if you're looking for something very easy to use: [ss-search](https://github.com/yann510/ss-search)